# Multiple Form GUI application C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a C# application . I am new to .NET programming. It's basically a big Windows Forms Application which displays various forms, all interlinked with each other based on user control. My main form is login page to validate the user to go to the Menu Form(second form), where there are options for the user to decide. So the main activity starts from the Menu Form(second form), it contains a label holding the username. From the Menu Form(second form), it goes to the third form which is a pop-up form,  which leads to the fourth form. Basically, hide the second form when moving to each form. Now from the fourth form, I want to go back to Menu Form(second form) without creating a new instance. I tried to do this without new instances but no luck. See code below:

**Second form (Menu):**

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    PopUp form3 = new Popup(); 
    form3.Show();

    // Hides the Menu Form(second form)
    this.Hide();
}
```

**Third Form:**

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {      
     var menu = new Menu();
     menu.Hide();

     // Hide Form #3
     Hide();
     form4.Show();

     // Hide Form #3
     Close();
 }
```

**Fourth Form:**

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(grpSaved == false)
    {
        Form5 form5 = new Form5();
        form5.Show();
        form5.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(unsaved_FormClosed);             
        grpSaved = true;
    }
    else
    {
        var menu = new Menu();
        Close();//closes fourth form

        menu.Show();
    }
}
```

This code creates a new instance of the Menu Form(second form). Please help me to get around this problem.

Comment: If the third and fourth forms are actually popups, don't hide the second form.  Instead, use `ShowDialog` to show the third form as a popup.  Then when the third form closes, control returns to the second form to do whatever it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While on the second form (Your main form) if you select a button or click a check box to access the third and fourth forms, try using a show dialog cod instead for the new form and then place you this.Show(); after the show dialog to ensure that when the form you opened is closed it will return you to the form you opened it from.

Example:

Instead of:

```
PopUp form3 = new Popup(); 
    form3.Show();  
    //hides the second (Menu) form
    this.Hide();
```

Try:

```
//Hide the second form
this.Hide();
//Bring up your PopUp form
using (PopUp form3 = new PopUp())
     form3.ShowDialog();
//When your PopUp form closes the code should continue and show the second form again.
this.Show();
```

So to stack the forms try the following:

```
//Menu Form
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
this.Hide();
using(PopUp form3 = new Popup()) 
    form3.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
} 

//PopUp Form
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  this.Hide();
  using(Task form4 = new Task())
      form4.ShowDialog();
  this.Close();      
 }

//Task Form
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Close();
}
```

The last button only needs to close the task form. Once it closes the code on the PopUp form will continue which will close the PopUp form and return you to your original Menu form without loading a new form, and clearing the form stack in the process.

It's a clean solution except that it does not inherently save the data from the other two forms. Clicking on the button on the Menu page again will bring up a new PopUp form.

Comment: Application runs in Login form:

Comment: private void click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((user.Text == username) && (pswd.Text == password))
            {
                Menu menu = new Menu();
                menu.Username = user.Text;
                //hides the login form
                this.Hide();      
                menu.ShowDialog();
            }

Comment: so the Menu form appears with username on its top and with 2 buttons.one is popupform and control form.Code for menu:

Comment: private void pop_up_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            //Hide the second form
            this.Hide();
            //Bring up your PopUp form
            using (Popup form3 = new Popup())
                form3.ShowDialog();
            
        }

        private void user_control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Hide();
            Control control = new Control();
            control.Show();
        }

Comment: In popupform ,I click Task1 button                                                     private void Task1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Hide();
            Task1 task = new Task1();
          task.Show();
        }

Comment: Now I am finally in Task1 form  ,contains 2 button .one is Go to menu button and another is subtask button.Basically, I want to go to Menu form without creating new instance that should appear with username I logged in.That's the reason ,I dont need new instance of Menu form which doesn't display  username. private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //how to go back to Menu without creating new instance???
        }

Comment: Please help! I couldn't proceed without solving this issue.

Comment: private void pop_up_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { //Hide the second form this.Hide(); //Bring up your PopUp form using (Popup form3 = new Popup()) form3.ShowDialog(); } private void user_control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Hide(); Control control = new Control(); control.Show(); } – user7274707 9 hours ago
     
In popupform ,I click Task1 button private void Task1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Hide(); Task1 task = new Task1(); task.Show(); } – user7274707

Comment: I see your problem. You are wanting to hit a button and open the next form and then hit a button and open the next form and then at the end come back to the original form yes?

Comment: For what you are looking for I would suggest stacking the forms using code. It would make it cleaner and would be simple. For example:

Comment: It worked! Thanks a ton!.One more question. I am currently doing this application in modal forms and after some research, I am thinking of doing this application in MDI or User control which I hope to control the forms in a better way as it is getting bigger. But I am not sure which one will be suited for my application as both looks similar to me. Can you  please explain the differences and give me suggestions to chose the one that fits my criteria.Thanks again.